# How to get values outside the loop - powershell

Tags: html, powershell

Hello I wrote small function to Check if website is available. I would like to take out value - status outside it and create a nice html output. I had to used loop to check each website from the $hash.

```
Function MyFunction{
clear-host
$hash = @{"ING"= "http://google.pl/" ; "youtube" = "https://youtube.com/" ;}
$weburl = $hash.Values 
foreach ($weburls in $weburl){ 
$HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($weburls)
$HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse() 
# We then get a response from the site.
$HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode # We then get the HTTP code as an integer.
If ($HTTP_Status -eq 404 -or $HTTP_Status -eq 503 -or $HTTP_Status -eq 403 ) {
    Write-Host "$weburls The Site may be down, please check. - status is $HTTP_Status!"
    $URLRESP = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $URLRESP | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  Status -Value "The Site may be down, please check!"
    [array]$URLRES += $URLRESP
}
Else {
    Write-Host "OK"
    $URLRESP = New-Object -TypeName psobject
    $URLRESP | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name  Status -Value "OK"
    [array]$URLRES += $URLRESP
}
$HTTP_Response.Close() # Finally, we clean up the http request by closing it.    }
```

Loop ends here. Now I am converting it to html with values - Name, Value, Link and here i want to add a new value - the "**Status**" with results like "ok" or "dead link" etc.

```
    $hash.GetEnumerator() | sort -Property Name | Select-Object Name, Value, Status | 
    ConvertTo-HTML -Head $headLink  -Property *,@{Label="Link";Expression={"
}

$html_url = MyFunction 
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($html_url) | Out-File  "\\......\scresult\test.htm" -Append
```

I have no idea how to put a value "status" outside it. Sorry I am not good with scripting at all and i do not have a clue how to do it. I have the feeling if i just put the output line inside the loop it will multiply per value.

Comment: Do youhave to have name? Why not just Value, Status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is 2 parts. How can I get the data? How can i pass it to a ConvertTo-HTML?

Your first question is solved by creating a `Arraylist` and adding a `PSCustomObject` with the properties you want to pass. This way you can ass to the final return a array of `Hashtables` with the same `Keys`.

```
function GetSiteStatus(){
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline)]
        [hashtable]$WebSiteInfo
    )
    process{
        $Response = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
        $WebSiteInfo.GetEnumerator() | %{
            $Item = $_
            try{ 
                $status = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $_.Value | %{
                    if(@('404','503','403') -match $_.StatusCode){
                        "$($Item.Key) The Site may be down, please check. - status is $($_.StatusCode)"
                    }else{
                        "OK"
                    }
                }
                $Response.Add([PSCustomObject]@{"Name"= $Item.Key; "Value"=$Item.Value; "Status"=$Status; "Link"=$($Item.value)}) | out-null
            }catch{
                $Status = "$($Item.Key), $_."
                $Response.Add([PSCustomObject]@{"Name"= $Item.Key; "Value"=$Item.Value; "Status"=$Status; "Link"=$($Item.value)}) | out-null
            }
        }
        return $Response
    }
}
```

As for the second question, this is how you use the function and pass the return into a `convertto-html` and `out-file.`

```
$HTML = @{
    "Test403" = "https://httpstat.us/403"; 
    "Test404" = "https://httpstat.us/404";
    "Test503" = "https://httpstat.us/503";
    "Google" = "http://www.Google.com";
    "GoogleFake" = "https://GoogleFAKE1312.com"
} | GetSiteStatus | ConvertTo-Html -Property Name,Value,Status,@{Label="Link";Expression={"<a href='$($_.Value)'>$($_.Name)</a>"}}

Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web
[System.Web.HttpUtility]::HtmlDecode($HTML) | Out-File C:\TEST\test.htm
```

Answer (score 1):

A few changes and here is a working script I was able to test. I think it will help you get what you are looking for

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Results = @()

Function MyFunction {
    Clear-Host
    $hash = @{
        "ING"     = "http://google.com/"
        "youtube" = "https://youtube.com/"
    }    
    $weburl = $hash.Values 
    foreach ($url in $weburl){ 
        $HTTP_Request = [System.Net.WebRequest]::Create($url)
        $HTTP_Response = $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
        $HTTP_Status = [int]$HTTP_Response.StatusCode

        If (($HTTP_Status -eq 404) -or ($HTTP_Status -eq 503) -or ($HTTP_Status -eq 403)) {
            Write-Host "$url The Site may be down, please check. - status is $HTTP_Status!"            
        }
        Else {
            Write-Host "$url is OK"            
        }
        $HTTP_Response.Close()

        $Result = [PSCustomObject]@{
            URL = $url
            Status = $HTTP_Status
        }
        $Results.Add($Result) | Out-Null
    }
}

MyFunction

$Results
```

**EDIT**

After looking at it again, if you cause a bad response, it will throw an exception. You would need to add some error handling such as a `try catch` and possibly parse the error to get the exact error code. I assumed it was returning an error code when I did my quick test.

> Exception calling "GetResponse" with "0" argument(s): "The remote server returned an error: (503) Server Unavailable."
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + $HTTP_Request.GetResponse()
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebException